# Some apps cannot be downloaded to new Tabs

Tags: android

I have just bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab, model GT-P7500. This Tab has WiFi and 3G/GSM, and uses a SIM card. It cannot be used as a telephone, but it supports sending and reception of SMSs. When I go to Android Market (using this tab), there are several apps which are not visible, and which cannot be downloaded to this tab. E.g. some of my own, which use SMS sending and reception. The Manifest for these apps (which cannot be downloaded to this tab) contains the following permissions:

```
android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
android.permission.SEND_SMS
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

The third one is e.g. required in order to be able to read the SIM card number.

When I download these apps to the tab locally, they work as expected. Hence there should be no reason to filter them out at the Market, and I cannot see why this is being done.

I have asked Android Market Support about this, but they seem to be unable to do anything about it. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? Does the problem lie with the Android Market, or with Samsung? Can it be fixed? When?

Comment: here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html you can read how android Market filters its applications. I think if you would like to view all apps, you must overwrite your device information, so that market will see what you want it to see

Comment: It am not sure what you mean. It does not matter whether I see the apps in question or not. It is all the users of this (and probably other tabs) that I am worried about. I want THEM to see these (and download) apps.

Comment: in this case you would most probably specify as less permissions as possible, so that markets filter will not distinguish devices based on some of their hardware specifications. so for instance app with "READ_PHONE_STATE" with for example "TelephonyManager" class will not be available to some phones that are not able to make calls

Comment: Even if this specific tab cannot make normal telephone calls, it is possible to read info about its SIM card from/in an app. Have you any idea how that can be done without specifying the READ_PHONE_STATE permission in the app's Manifest file?

Comment: Anyway; I am pretty sure that the permissions which are causing the problem, are RECEIVE_SMS and SEND_SMS. The reason for believing that, is that I have two very similar apps, where one have these permissions (in its Manifest file) while the other does not. Otherwise, their Manifest files are identical. The app with the SMS permissions does NOT show up on the tab, while the other one does.

Answer (score 0):

The original Samsung Galaxy Tab did not support SMS. Apparently yours does. Whether Samsung failed to notify the Android Market team of this or whether the Android Market team failed to establish a separate filtering profile, I cannot say.

You fail to indicate what app this is and whether is needs SMS capability to work or not. If it does not *need* SMS capability (but could use it if available), add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

to your manifest, to indicate that you do not absolutely need telephony capabilities. To see whether the device has telephony, use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()`.

If your app definitely needs SMS capability to run, then it will simply not be available on this tablet, until such time as Samsung and/or the Android Market team sort out the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer. You are right that some Samsung Galaxy tabs do not support SMS (e.g. Galaxy Tab 10.1 model GT-P7510) while others/newer do (e.g. Galaxy Tab 10.1 model GT-P7500). My apps absolutely need to use SMSs, so I guess that I have to wait until Samsung and/or the Android Market team will sort out the problem. I hope it will be soon, as this could well be a general problem, also affecting other devices.